# Do While loop to blink cell every second is killing performance

Tags: excel, vba, do-while

I wrote a macro to check if a date is the last day of a month.
If so this cell should blink every 1 second, so I'm calling a Do While loop.

I want to start the Sub when I open the worksheet, so I added a `Sub Workbook_Open()`. If the date is the last day of the month this sub is called as expected.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call CellBlink
End Sub
```

The performance is so bad, that it is nearly impossible to work with this sheet.

```vb
Do While Today = EndOfMonth

    CellThatBlinks.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

    CellThatBlinks.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

    CellThatBlinks.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

    DoEvents

Loop
```

Comment: `Do While Today = EndOfMonth` -- this will continue looping while this is true. When do you want it to stop? More importantly, how do you intend to work with the sheet while this is running?

Comment: `Application.OnTime()` would perhaps be a better solution, as the current code blocks execution while waiting. Create a Sub that just toggles the colour of the cell.

Comment: I don't know much about excel, I just have some basic experience in programming and this is for a friend of mine.
If I have understood him correctly this should blink the whole day

Comment: `Application.Wait` let VBA pause execution, but as long as the execution is not completely stopped, Excel cannot work - except if code hits a `DoEvents`-statement (Which is only the case every 2 seconds). As DS_Longon wrote, use `Application.OnTime`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/Concepts/Cells-and-Ranges/make-a-cell-blink for an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Application.OnTime` is a way to loop without blocking execution.

First `Name` the cell in the Workbook that you want to blink, eg "BlinkCell", using Formulas / Define Name.

Then put this code in a Module (not a Workbook or Worksheet object):

```
Option Explicit
Dim strLast As String

Public Sub CellBlink()
    Dim rngBlink As Range
      
    If WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Now, 0) = Int(Now) Then
        Set rngBlink = Range("BlinkCell")
        
        Dim onIndex, offIndex
        onIndex = 3
        offIndex = 0
        
        If rngBlink.Interior.ColorIndex = onIndex Then
            rngBlink.Interior.ColorIndex = offIndex
        Else
            rngBlink.Interior.ColorIndex = onIndex
        End If
        
        strLast = Format(Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "hh:mm:ss")
        Application.OnTime strLast, "CellBlink"
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub CancelBlink()
    If Len(strLast) > 0 Then
        Application.OnTime strLast, "CellBlink", Schedule:=False
        Range("BlinkCell").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

and this code in the ThisWorkbook object:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    CellBlink
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel as Boolean) 
    CancelBlink
End Sub
```

How it works: Once the `Workbook_Open` event is fired, the global subroutine `CellBlink` is called. In the sheet, the blinking cell is Name'd "BlinkCell". CellBlink checks whether today's date is the end of month: if it is then the cell colour is toggled (on->off->on etc). Finally, the `Application.OnTime` function is called to run this same CellBlink macro in one second's time. The time that the macro is schedule to run is saved as a string. Running the `CancelBlink` macro will terminate the loop until `CellBlink` is called again.

Comment: Great. To test it today (`02/05` - not the end of the month), one can replace `Int(Now)` with `Int(Now) + 23`.

Comment: @DS_London Thank you, sir. I appreciate the work you put into that Answer.